# Remove partial matching duplicate lines and retain longest line

Tags: code-golf, string

Write the shortest possible program to remove all partial matched duplicates from a list and only retain the longest lines. Sort order does not matter.

For following inputs, the intent is to search for the string `reminder` followed by a number and retain the longest unique `reminder + number` lines.

## Some rules

- `reminder` is a hard-coded word, case-sensitive.
- All lines contain exactly one match.
- There is always a space between `reminder` and the number.
- Only positive, whole numbers are used in the matches (not necessarily a contiguous set).
- Lines with same length for the same reminder are possible. It does not matter what line is chosen.
- Sort order of output does not matter.

## Inputs

```
A short reminder 1
This is the longest reminder 1 available
This is the longest reminder 2 available, different length
A short reminder 2
A short reminder 3
This is the longest reminder 3 available, another different length
Another short reminder 3
A reminder -1 but really a short reminder 42
This is the longest reminder but really a short reminder 42.
```

## Expected output

```
This is the longest reminder 1 available
This is the longest reminder 2 available, different length
This is the longest reminder 3 available, another different length
This is the longest reminder but really a short reminder 42.
```

Shortest code wins

---

Background: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63405349/52598) stackoverflow question

Comment: What's a "partial matched duplicate"?

Comment: @Zgarb - I have adjusted my question. Does that answer yours?

Comment: Nice! *Now* it turns into a fun challenge. (I assume you mean find the longest prefixes right?)

Comment: Is `match` a hard-coded word, or is it taken as a separate input? Is it case-sensitive? Can there be lines that don't contain match plus a number? Does there have to be a space between the match and the number? Can the number be negative? I'm sorry to ask so many questions, but it's important to know what exactly the task is before you get many wrong answers.

Comment: @Zgarg - valid questions. I'll adjust my question :)

Comment: Please, can I have test cases for your rule addition?

Comment: @petStorm - Not sure what to add. Your solution works so you interpreted my intent correctly.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Not really, it matches negative decimals as well. Give me a sec to fix that...

Comment: @petStorm - I have added a fourth sample.

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what's going on with the `-2` match. (Downvote my answer as you see fit, I really want to give up.)

Comment: Do the lines need to be returned in the same order as the input?

Comment: Will there ever be two lines with the same length and same `match #`? e.g. `a match 1 here` and `here a match 1`?

Comment: @petStorm - That was in response to your input about negative numbers.The `match -2 ` in that line should not matter.Only the `match 4` in that line does.

Comment: @DomHastings - no, sortorder does not matter. Same length and same match is possible but which one is chosen does not matter. I have added that to the rules.

Comment: Are the set of positive integers used guaranteed to be one through some N inclusive as in your example or can they be any set of positive numbers? (I believe the spec as it stands is the latter, but the former may make for terser code in some languages.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan - the *intent* is any set of positive numbers. Looking at regex, that's just a `\d+` so I don't see how you could go terser than that? Do you have an example?

Comment: In languages that do not have regex support, it might well be terser if the code can assume the [1..N] input style. I just wanted to confirm which you wanted, which is totally up to you.

Comment: @JonathanAllan - You know my intent but I don't now how to translate that requirement in my rules so please, if you think it will clear up the question, feel free to add that.

Comment: Are occurrences of `match` _always_ followed by an integer (be they negative or positive) or are lines like `A match for match 42` possible?

Comment: @JonathanAllan - Unless I'm mistaken, this example covers that? `A match -1 but really a short match 42`

Comment: No, in that example both `match` are immediately followed by a space and then an integer (while `for` in my example is not an integer).

Comment: @JonathanAllan - I see. That's possible. I have adjusted `This is the longest match -2 but really a short match 4.` to `This is the longest match but really a short match 4.` That doesn't invalidates Jo Kings answer.

Comment: @JonathanAllan - I thought I originally covered all cases but being complete is an art in itself :)

Comment: For future reference, it's best not to define any rules by an example but to define upfront, possibly with a worked example, and then to have tests that cover edge-cases.

Comment: Can a line have a match without a number? A number without a match?

Comment: @xnor - no. Every line contains the equivalent of the regex `match \d+`. Hindsight 20/20, I should have named `match` to something else :(

Comment: Suggested test case: "A reminder 0 is not a positive whole number, reminder 1"
Trips every answer relying on "\d+". Alternatively, adjust the wording to "non-negative" to include 0 (in which case, this test case is invalid)

Comment: All "\d+" answers are broken anyway, since they will match stuff like "reminder 04".

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys - Not easy getting the specs right. 0 and/or leading 0's are no problem. Would adding the `\d+` regex to the rules cover that sufficiently?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers I think so, although it may potentially break two of the answers (since I can't read them). Changing the spec in a way that breaks existing answers is usually not allowed.

Comment: @SE-stopfiringthegoodguys - tried all the answers and none would break but I rather  not add it if it's frowned upon.

Comment: Can you add a few test cases with integers that are _not_ preceded by `reminder` to cover solutions that might, naïvely, just try to match a run of digits on its own?

Comment: Well, leaving things as-is would leave all of them broken. (though it's not your fault that they aren't following the spec). If you want to permit 0 and leading 0s, you should add it, which is luckily not problematic since everyone had already made that assumption.

Comment: @Shaggy - I'm at my 10th edit, I really rather not mess with it any further. Perhaps adding a note? Feel free to do so by the way.

Comment: I read the text several times and I still don't know what is being asked. Is each line a different input? Or do we take the full list of strings as a single input? How do we decide which lines survive and which don't? Sorry, downvoting for now

Comment: @LuisMendo - Each line is a different input. If you do a diff between the inputs and expected outputs, you should see the pattern otherwise I can only recommend to look at the solutions to get the idea.

Comment: If each line is an input, I don't get why there are 9 inputs and 4 outputs. I'm not asking you to explain; maybe it's just me. I only wanted to justify that I'm downvoting because I find the challenge confusing

Comment: @LuisMendo - I'll try anyway. There are 4 reminders: reminder 1, reminder 2, reminder 3 and reminder 42. I want to find the longest inputs containing those lines.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks. Are you sure each line is an input? How can you find the longest if the program only receives one input?

Comment: @LuisMendo - English is not my native language so we seem to be stuck on semantics. Assume the input (9 lines) is the content of a file, does that clear things up?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers So the program takes all inputs at once? Yes, that makes sense. Thanks. I removed my downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
é.¡#I¡εнžm(Ã}þ}€θ
```

05AB1E doesn't have any regex, so figuring out the best approach with test case containing negative numbers or multiples spaces between the string and the number (i.e. `reminder   42`) was a bit tricky, but still pretty happy with how short it turned out.

First input is a list of string lines, and the second input is the hard-coded string to match.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Eq9QwuVPQ8tPLf1wt6j@3I1DjfXHt5X@6hpzbkd//9HKzkqFGfkF5UoFKXmZualpBYpGCrpKIVkZBYrAFFJRqpCTn5eemoxsgKFxLLEzJzEpJxUQkqNEEp1FFIy09JSi1LzShRyUvPSSzKAmjEsN8ImaEzIGmNkaxLz8oGKirBaB5XCYr4jgqtrqJBUCpJOzMmpVEhEV21iRMg5@HXrgbSjqNc1NDJGdU0QPKwNDBAyQGBihKRQTymWC8YDAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
é             # Sort the (implicit) input-list of lines by length (shortest to longest)
 .¡           # Group the lines by:
   #          #  Split the string on spaces
    I¡        #  Split that list on the second input-word
      ε       #  Map each inner list of strings to:
       н      #   Only leave the first part of the list
        žm    #   Push builtin 9876543210
          (   #   Negate it to -9876543210
           Ã  #   Only keep those characters from the string
      }þ      #  After the map, only leave strings consisting of just digits;
              #  so this will remove empty strings and negative numbers from the list
  }€          # After the group by: map over each group:
    θ         #  And only leave the last (thus longest) line
              # (after which the resulting list of lines is output implicitly)
```

[See this for a step-by-step on how the input is transformed into the output.](https://tio.run/##hZKxTuNAEIZ7nmJkmiA5gThUSAiloEiFBNehK9bJ2h5ps2vtrolS0Nw9SUokSjjdFaSwRWvxDLxImLUNJodFLFuyPd///zNjK8NC5JuNN5FokQlAmWa2L9DYE/D80/zP2Z53pbTlMwiXYBOOGgSXsU0M9EziKsaCVSCUjOn2wMmKu1p4zqYJCJQcTCrQOgeTsik3Dnr9db@/hZFPjSnpgppWFkrPHD4pH/JVzV9IsaQm2A2vuAg1SVOmSRkBd2YoJdfwPgUl0fny1KmW2Tzk2nxInY8TlY/P63mvfCh@33bqHGdgqqShFJSxM1AOmWGMVOnZBA3QuUi45rDgEGuVpcQcND0Va78yHkeWmnWeNREu/dqpDRPM2MNmw9uT1pLeIkE3No2Rabosba6Kyf8Vd4N8tT/JV@Xjy5MbiQYq1reUX/71N5trbwzVZwTN5yhn1MnQ870fTfNVeJPbAsBuGAoWCr4LDVrUp81EEe1C2uYPIvGX8KDr5WhXzOhzDJOKIN0Z15Q6/MftY38IYebKTNBXYP/Tx8Gudr5XD5x8i@8Pg9F2N5cfuz46ait0HAefwIH3c@/96Q0)

Comment: Amazing what  people come up with

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>85 82</s>  79 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>-!b[a.length]).filter(s=>a[k=/reminder \d+/.exec(s)]^(a[k]=1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHBbsIwEETvfMU2J1tNjBJ6NRL/wC0N0iZZJ6aujWy3Kl8fjEAFtaWKtKfZNztjeY@fGDqvD7GwrqdJyQnlGkVwPjKGecvlunhqaxSG7BDHhgulTSTPQsLqN7n09K5tTx5e@@eloC/qWODNjqVlI0vOp87Z4AwJ4wamWL0AyDYQxhQA394yy8/6dtQB0sSRwDg7ULhnIHXVBltDM@jqRufQa6XIk41wecXF/6tF9UBfzchb3eehdQnyj3Kv279TNjelKKH9OBNozBHwp@GlmtHr/wMiWzTpi04)

#### How?

We first sort all strings from longest to shortest.

```javascript
a.sort((a, b) =>
  -!b[a.length]  // 0 if 'b' is longer than 'a', -1 otherwise
)
```

We then filter the strings, keeping only the first occurrence of each `reminder N` key. The underlying object of the input array `a[]` is re-used to keep track of the keys that were already encountered.

```javascript
.filter(s =>
  a[k = /reminder \d+/.exec(s)]
  ^
  (a[k] = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 20 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of strings. Output is sorted by the matched number, in lexicographical order.

```
ü_f`ã„ %d+` gÃ®ñÊÌ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=cVI&code=/F9mYOOEGAAgJWQrYCBnw67xysw&input=IkEgc2hvcnQgcmVtaW5kZXIgMQpUaGlzIGlzIHRoZSBsb25nZXN0IHJlbWluZGVyIDEgYXZhaWxhYmxlClRoaXMgaXMgdGhlIGxvbmdlc3QgcmVtaW5kZXIgMiBhdmFpbGFibGUsIGRpZmZlcmVudCBsZW5ndGgKQSBzaG9ydCByZW1pbmRlciAyCkEgc2hvcnQgcmVtaW5kZXIgMwpUaGlzIGlzIHRoZSBsb25nZXN0IHJlbWluZGVyIDMgYXZhaWxhYmxlLCBhbm90aGVyIGRpZmZlcmVudCBsZW5ndGgKQW5vdGhlciBzaG9ydCByZW1pbmRlciAzCkEgcmVtaW5kZXIgLTEgYnV0IHJlYWxseSBhIHNob3J0IHJlbWluZGVyIDQyClRoaXMgaXMgdGhlIGxvbmdlc3QgcmVtaW5kZXIgYnV0IHJlYWxseSBhIHNob3J0IHJlbWluZGVyIDQyLiIKLVI) (Header splits input string on newlines)

```
ü_f`... %d+` gÃ®ñÊÌ     :Implicit input of array
ü                       :Group and sort by
 _                      :Passing each through the following function
  f                     :  Match
   `... %d+`            :    Compressed string "reminder %d+", which translates to the RegEx /reminder \d+/g
             g          :  Get first match ('Cause matching returns an array)
              Ã         :End grouping
               ®        :Map
                ñ       :  Sort by
                 Ê      :    Length
                  Ì     :  Get last element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), <s>134</s> 132 bytes

```python
import re
def f(l,d={}):
 for s in l:
  if len(d.get(n:=re.sub('.*reminder (\\d+).*','\\1',s))or'')<len(s):d[n]=s
 return d.values()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJPb4MgFL/7KV56ATpHou7QmHnod9ht7oDhoSQUDWCTZtlnd7i6tdniIjf4/SXvDZfQ9bY4DG6a9GnoXQCHiUQFippUVu8frExA9Q48aAsmXkArMGip5C0GasvKIfdjQwnfOzxpK9EBrWv5wPiepKSuM5J6xnpHCHuehZ6V8tW@VT6JWWF0FiQ/CzOip2wK6IOHCmgMAtgdwXfXUotztkuvyEunYyUPoUMwvW2j7o4F4iy0EY3BTfz8xk9BaqXQoQ3zN9vQfTv86ZKvIsWm1OI@Vdg@ktx6@oKvJR1vb48ZNOPMEcZcQPyWPOWb2v1vwRcPlvwsh6Jfw5sXJp7BaRvirKdP)

Tried recursive lambda approach but it's longer:

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 148 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,d={}:l and(len(d.get(n:=re.sub('.*reminder (\\d+).*','\\1',s:=l.pop()))or'')<len(s)and d.update([(n,s)])or f(l,d))or d.values()
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJBasMwEEX3PsWQjaXUFcTpIph6kTt0F2cho3EskGUhyYFQenZ3nKQktLhYaKX/5v8ZRu4S295ud86PY1Ma2dVKgslU@flVGJBWMYOWKXHCyGxRehRhqFkq1h47bRV6YFWlXrhYp1laVZs0C0VphOsd45z3Pk35@@QQOHmBEoNTMiI7MJsFfiQAGkZxE0rqWZoBA@OJ7lzvI3gcI4YYoIRDAnRWewjtTbnHb1bZTflodQC6sUUwvT1R3RMF8iy1kbXBRXz@4DNQumnQo41Ak5xi@@Pwp5d8VtkuSt0@p0rbE@Tn0@/6XNL@8fa6gXqYGGnMBeTvkrd8UXf/W4i7xzFpaJXkYmmz1@Xx4io4r22kfzB@Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 48 bytes

```perl6
*.sort(-*.comb).unique(:as({~m/reminder\s\d+/}))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCoJAEIbvPsWcwrVcUaNDkeA7dPSy5qgLu2vtroFEvboZFEqGMJeZ/5v55oJa7HrZwaqEY@9R02jr@h49NzIntFX82qK7Z8a9P2WgUXJVoM5MVqyDByH9wSldwRUakiTUsK5PwdTDCfiiEDqnmhsYytYIolEVmmkM7Ma4YLnAZTAawQ0UvCxRo7IgUFW2dmbaaD6KlwXxVMBUM0D6j@gTzG6nY@OHkLfvkAnRAftlt9HyI8u79AU)

Sorts by longest first, then gets the unique elements by the reminder number.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 68 bytes

```
O#$`
$.&
O#$`.*reminder (\d+).*
$1
.*(reminder \d+)(.*¶(.*\1\b))+
$3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5NCoMwEIX3OcVAQ9HYBvy5gCfopksXjXU0gTRCTAu9WA/Qi6URikotwhAm730zbyw6ZYT3px29EMr3ZGw4s3hTpkELUdUkMWeEpoSzaJJHNeLs/QpPlVZ1HCeE5t6XMMjeOpjAlJylGiCUkwi6Nx0OSxvEQygtao3bYDaDB2hU26JF40Cj6Zwkq9gsSG5ccBUDznJerNF8OzhfBgvTB8j@OeBrrHaX8@eYQn0fTaH1E8QvW2Tbh2zP8g8) Explanation:

```
O#$`
$.&
```

Sort (in ascending order) numerically by length.

```
O#$`.*reminder (\d+).*
$1
```

Sort numerically by matched number, keeping lines with the same number sorted in length order.

```
.*(reminder \d+)(.*¶(.*\1\b))+
$3
```

Keep only the last line of consecutive lines with the same matched number.

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 39 bytes

```
ÎÄÒ0J
ú!
ò/reminder ä
y2e0dw+VGç0¾/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3Df4ZbDkwy8uA7vUuQ6vEm/KDU3My8ltUjh8BKuSqNUg5Ry7TD3w8uFDA7t00/h4v//31GhOCO/qEQBrtCQKyQjs1gBiEoyUhVy8vPSU4uRpRUSyxIzcxKTclLxKzRCKNRRSMlMS0stSs0rUchJzUsvyeDCsNYIU8gYvwXGyBYk5uUDFRVhsQgqgWG2I4Kja6iQVAqSTMzJqVRIRFdrYoTfIfj16gEA)

```
Î                 # on every line (:%norm)
 Ä                # (M-D)uplicate the line
  Ò0              # (M-R)eplace all characters with '0'
    J             # (J)oin with the original line
                  # This turns each line into "0000000000 reminder 1"
ú!                # Reverse (M-z)ort (cursor ends up on first line)
ò                 # (M-r)ecursively (until error)
 /reminder ä      # goto /reminder \d/ (longest reminder X, here we find X)
y2e               # (y)ank (e)nd of (2) words: reminder \d+>
   0dw            # goto beginning and (d)elete (w)ord (the 0s)
      +           # goto start of next line
       VG         # highlight until end
         ç^R0¾/d  # in this highlighted region delete lines matching:
                  # (^R)egister 0 - contains the reminder (y)anked earlier
^O                # Jump back to prev cursor position and repeat until error
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>No (direct) regex support in Jelly (it's only indirectly available by executing Python code).</sup>

```
ðœṣ“Ç§ƥ»;⁶¤Ḋe€ÞṪf)ØDĠị⁸LÞṪ$€
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of characters which yields a list of lists of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///whqOTH@5c/KhhzuH2Q8uPLT202/pR47ZDSx7u6Ep91LTm8LyHO1elaR6e4XJkwcPd3Y8ad/iAhVSAcv8f7t5yuD3y/39HheKM/KIShaLU3My8lNQiBUOukIzMYgUgKslIVcjJz0tPLUaWVkgsS8zMSUzKScWv0AihUEchJTMtLbUoNa9EISc1L70kgwvDWiNMIWP8FhgjW5CYlw9UVITFIqgEhtmOCI6uoUJSKUgyERisConoak2M8DsEv149AA)** (footer just splits at newlines, calls the Link and joins back by newlines.)

#### How?

```
ðœṣ“Ç§ƥ»;⁶¤Ḋe€ÞṪf)ØDĠị⁸LÞṪ$€ - Link: list of lists of characters, X
                  ØD         - digit characters
ð                )           - dyadic chain for each (line in X) - i.e. f(line, digit characters)
 œṣ                          -   split at substrings equal to:
          ¤                  -     nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
   “Ç§ƥ»                     -       compressed string "reminder"
         ⁶                   -       space character
        ;                    -       concatenate -> "reminder "
           Ḋ                 -   dequeue (leaving only strings to the right of a "match ")
              Þ              -   sort (these "parts") by
             €               -   for each (character, c, in part):
            e                -     (c) exists in (digit characters)?
               Ṫ             -   tail - giving us the single part starting with positive digit
                                        characters - N.B. a '0...' is always less, if present
                f            -   filter-keep (digit characters) - thus "42..." becomes "42"
                    Ġ        - group indices by value
                     ị       - index into:
                      ⁸      -   X - giving us a list of lists of lines with equal "number"
                           € - for each:
                          $  -   last two links as a monad:
                        Þ    -     sort by:
                       L     -       length
                         Ṫ   -     tail
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-M5.10.0`, 59 bytes

Uses the same approach as @Arbauld's answer, sorts the input by length then discards any sentences that contain a previously seen match.

```perl
say grep/reminder \d+/&&!${$&}++,sort{$b=~y///c-length$a}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BDoIwDIbvPEVNCBeECchNTXgAbx69DCmwZG5kmyaE6KM7MRohYkh6ab@//dqg4qm1mrZQKWyIwjMTBSo4Fj7xvIXbud7N95daKtO5@fbeEkJOAUdRmdqlt83O2gx03WP47kbOoWYa@jI1ApeiQj3GQK@UcZpznA/GQ3AJBStLVCgMvOXORBtPR8m8IBkLqJB9SP0RfcDkdjY0QQT55QUp5y3Q3@w6nn9kfjd0HrIxTAptg30aRqtw9QQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 53 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.sort_by{|s|-s.size}.uniq{|s|s[/reminder \d+/]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BC4JAEIXv/orBa6loXQ38D13CJEYcc2Fba2cNzPztphAZJQpzmfe@x3u6SusuDztnhw26XGpzSuvmyU@HXRYPat1KidsgcOxpugiVkYZjtvKStu0wjO0IuOhj8DF9e23Z@0Iw9GcKAlmqM/E3AXhHITGVtMgGI7uGTOQ5aVIGJKmzKYb0X38wqW4G9fDzzzZvvptRlT2kpxe8vanGaPwdH9Jq8FHKGvAX3waLi@bjrp1Y1rUyDHmMSfcC)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 100 bytes

```python
lambda a:{max((j for j in a if'reminder '+i in j),key=len)for i in' '.join(a).split()if i.isdigit()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVFBasMwELznFUsulqhriN1TwIf8ocde1liy1pUlI6mlJuTtjpSkTWhxsdiLZmZnFmacgrKmmmX9NmscmhYB98cBvxjrQVoHPZABBJKZEwOZVjjIniiBPc/fxVRrYXgSJiyDrOgtGYa88KOmwDhJoIJ8S136neYgfPBQA9tAfNsDeGVdgB/z3Ta/Mq@KPMQJSoC2pot7DyrATySNjRar9OVdn0NLUgonTIB4exfUt8OfW8pFplqVWj2morFR5JbTb/xS0uGOPe@g@Uga1HqK5fxaeSlXXfe/RXHz4JtUrk@FS3Ypj@8vxOjIBOb5fAY)

Test cases borrowed from Noodle9.